# Storm topology stops emitting after StormServerHandler Netty error caused by OptionalDataException

Tags: netty, apache-storm, kryo, optionaldataexception

We have a storm cluster running with 3 nodes and multiple topologies. We use `apache-storm-1.2.2` with `java 1.8.0_162`

Currently we have the problem that a random topology stops emitting at random times after an error occurs and the Netty server is unavailable. This can happen after couple of hours or several days.

Since we haven't changed anything in the logic of storm bolts emitting or executing data, we currently have no clue how such an error can be thrown. Also it is questionable why the whole topology stops working after such an error.

It seems like there is a problem with the deserialization of some HashMap. But we can't figure out how this can happen.

Here the error of one of the workers which causes the failure:

```
2019-09-24 14:31:02.414 o.a.s.m.n.StormServerHandler Netty-server-localhost-6727-worker-2 [ERROR] server errors in handling the request
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.OptionalDataException
        at org.apache.storm.serialization.SerializableSerializer.read(SerializableSerializer.java:58) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:793) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:689) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoValuesDeserializer.deserializeFrom(KryoValuesDeserializer.java:37) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoTupleDeserializer.deserialize(KryoTupleDeserializer.java:50) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.messaging.DeserializingConnectionCallback.recv(DeserializingConnectionCallback.java:56) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.messaging.netty.Server.enqueue(Server.java:134) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.messaging.netty.Server.received(Server.java:255) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.messaging.netty.StormServerHandler.messageReceived(StormServerHandler.java:61) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:310) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: java.io.OptionalDataException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1587) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1407) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
        at org.apache.storm.serialization.SerializableSerializer.read(SerializableSerializer.java:56) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
        ... 32 more
```

After this error is thrown, all other workers for this specific toplogy will stop working and we have to kill and redeploy.

The logs of the other workers either show nothing useful or this:

```
2019-09-24 14:31:03.012 o.a.s.m.n.Client Thread-32-disruptor-worker-transfer-queue [ERROR] connection to Netty-Client-HOSTE_NAME/IP:PORT is unavailable
2019-09-24 14:31:03.053 o.a.s.m.n.Client client-worker-1 [WARN] Re-connection to HOSTE_NAME/IP:PORT was successful but 4 messages has been lost so far
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of notes that may help you narrow down the issue, based on what you posted:

Regarding your topology idling, you should try upgrading to at least Storm 1.2.3. You may be affected by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-3055.

Your stack trace shows that you're using Java serialization for some of your tuples. I think what is happening here is that one of your workers has serialized a tuple, which is sent to another worker and then deserialization of that tuple fails. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OptionalDataException.html.

First I think you should try switching off Java serialization. It's slow and you probably don't want it in a production topology anyway. See https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.3/Serialization.html.

Second, the next time your topology is hanging (assuming an upgrade to 1.2.3 doesn't fix it), I would try using `jstack` to get thread dumps for the idle workers. This should tell you why the topology isn't doing anything.

Finally, you could try temporarily logging the byte arrays at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/5b01c78d053b2b8e2b7e6a4a8acd4c822924bbf9/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/serialization/SerializableSerializer.java#L51, maybe they'll give you an idea what's going wrong when you see the exception. The exception you're getting indicates that the byte array doesn't contain the expected data for a serialized HashMap. In order to add this logging you will need to edit and build Storm, see https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md#building for how to do this.

Comment: The problem is, that in our production environment, we are not allowed to just install new software. Therefore tools like jstack or building Storm isn't a option. 

About the bug you posted, i don't think we are affected. Our workers successfully re-connect after the failure. They just don't start working again. 

As you mentioned, we think the problem lies between the serialization and deserialization when workers communicate with each other. We just don't understand in which case this can happen. We basically only emit one Object which has some HashMaps in it.

Comment: In what case are workers communicating with each other and serialize/deserialize the tuples?

Comment: Any time you have a bolt or spout in one worker that needs to send the tuple to another worker. It might be helpful for you to set this option https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/5b01c78d053b2b8e2b7e6a4a8acd4c822924bbf9/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/Config.java#L339. This forces Storm to serialize tuples even when sending tuples between bolts internally in a worker.